# TBuf to TInt Symbian

Tags: c++, symbian, descriptor

I simply wanna convert a TBuf to TInt in Symbian. I tried to do it the following way:

```
TBuf<2> buf;
buf.Copy( _L("10"));

TInt valInt;
TLex8 lex(buf);
lex.Val(valInt);
```

Here I get then the error message:

```
Error:  #289: no instance of constructor "TPtrC8::TPtrC8" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (TBuf<2>)
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `TLex8`, you have to use `TBuf8`.

Try this (My Symbian C++ is rusty, but this should be close):

```
TBuf8<2> buf;
buf.Copy(_L8("10"));

TInt valInt;
TLex8 lex(buf);
lex.Val(valInt);
```

Comment: .. or alternatively, use TLex (which is an alias for TLex16). BTW, `buf.Copy("10")` won't work, you need e.g. `_L8("10")` to make it a descriptor literal.